# How to setup a WPF App with various features

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I want to create a WPF App in VS which should have various features (no serperate applications!).
The MainWindow should containt several Icon's (like App Icon's on Smartphone) which represents each of my features. So the MainWindow should be as an overview of my features. How do I need to realize it?

- Which toolbar object represents an Icon? (Button?)
- If I click on the Icon (Button?) the new feature should be showed as fullscreen (like on a Smartphone by clicking/starting an App). Which feature of WPF should I use to show the Page/Window of the Feature? If I close the feature the MainWindow should be showed again. I would be glad about a code example

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This question is likely too broad to get you the answers you are looking for, but a good place to start is with the [`Window`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window?view=net-5.0) class.

Once you create your buttons, you can spawn a new `Window` for your distinct feature. The [`Window.ShowDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.showdialog?view=net-5.0) method will allow the new feature to remain active until it is closed. Setting the [`Window.Owner`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.owner?view=net-5.0) property will allow the new feature to return control to `MainWindow`.

I'd recommend trying some of these features out then coming back with *specific* questions you might have.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:class="MainWindow">
    <!-- ... -->
    <Button Click="Feature1_Click" Content="Open Feature 1"/>
    <Button Click="Feature2_Click" Content="Open Feature 2"/>
    <!-- ... -->
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public class MainWindow : Window 
{
    //...
    private void Feature1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        new Feature1Window
        {
            Owner = this
        }.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void Feature2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        new Feature2Window
        {
            Owner = this
        }.ShowDialog();
    }
    // ...
}
```